# Python setuptools: Install scripts as symlinks?

Tags: python, command-line, setuptools

When you install a package with `-e` if you change the code underlying an entrypoint with `console_scripts` then the new version is used.

This appears not to be the case with the `scripts` argument. Here you need to reinstall the scripts before the new code starts being used - which is a bit of a pain for development. Is there a way to make `setuptools` install `scripts` with symlinks so that I can change the underlying script files and have them immediately be used.

Comment: Hint: prepend them to `$PATH`

Comment: That works. I sort of want `activate` in a virtualenv to do this tho.. and hae other people be able to sue this.